# Ошибка android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException at FilePickerFragment.kt:97

Tags: android

В боевом приложении столкнулся с проблемой на устройствах: Xiaomi, Redmi, POCO:

```
Binary XML file line #25 in app:layout/fragment_file_picker: Binary XML 
file line #25 in ru.jcat.jcat:layout/fragment_file_picker: Error 
inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25 in 
app/fragment_file_picker: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

На 25 строке находится векторное изображение
У себя воспроизвести не получается.
Почитал, что это из-за проблем с апк, если их распространяют в интернете:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52474885/590947.

Но проблема, что я открыто не распространяю апк. Выкладываю апк только на: РуСтор, НашСтор, ХуавэйСтор. В плэй маркет ааб.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался? Как решали, что делали?

Попробовал воспроизвести проблему на своих устройствах - не помогло.
Также попробовал `extractor apk`, в итоге где приложение установилось тоже все ок.

Где есть разница по плотности пикселей, апк просто не устанавливается.
Но у меня к сожалению нет устройств Xiaomi, Redmi, POCO.

Comment: а на строке 25 что находится? или `app:layout/fragment_file_picker` это системный файл?

Comment: На 25 строке находится векторное изображение
Извиняюсь не добавил в описание проблемы.